# Eclipse Luna + WildFly 9

Tags: wildfly, eclipse-luna, wildfly-9

Can I use Eclipse Luna with WildFly 9 server ? Or should I move to Eclipse Mars ? I'm asking because I can't create a WildFly 9 server on my Eclipse but I can create a WildFly 8 server. I checked my Jboss Tools plugin which seems to be up to date (version 4.2.6). On Eclipse Mars a 4.3.0 version is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see below links, all informations show [JBoss Tools 4.3.0 Final](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/mars/4.3.0.Final.html) release is not appropriate for Eclipse Luna.

1. Check JBoss Tools column on [JBoss Tools Download Overview](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/overview.html).
2. Check installation part in [Blog Announcement of JBoss Tools for Eclipse Mars](http://tools.jboss.org/blog/ga-for-mars.html).
3. Check server section on [Documentation of JBoss Tools 4.3.0 Final](http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html#server).

If there is no any policy or another, moving Eclipse Mars is better choice to work stable and prevent future conflicts. Lastly, I have tried to download the bundle and install it manually but process is blocked by Eclipse Luna.

Comment: The hazards of referencing external links exposed! Clearly they've updated it. As you can see from the language I used, even I was not convinced it was true

Answer (score 1):

The [JBoss Tools Download](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/) site claims that the current 4.3 release can be installed into Eclipse Luna.

You may need to download the bundle and install it manually.

That said, if you are not constrained by some policy or another then you should consider upgrading to Eclipse Mars.